# Javascript - Fill input with iframe-in Value

Tags: javascript, iframe, input, fill

I wanna fill input with my iframe-in Value.
i have two html file. 1.html and 2.html
First one (1.html) is like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IFRAME TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" id="mylovelytextbox"><br />
<iframe src="2.html" id="mylovelyiframe">
</body>
</html>
```

And second one (2.html) is like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="thisone" value="mylovelychangedvalue">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanna fill mylovelytextbox in 1.html with thisone's value.
How can i do that?
-Sorry for bad english :(

Edit:

I run the code with @stano's help :) Now, my code is like that:

```
<html> <head> <title>IFRAME TEST</title> </head> <body> <input type="text" value="" id="mylovelytextbox"><input type="button" onClick="var iframe = document.getElementById('mylovelyiframe');console.log(iframe,doc,el);var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;var el = document.getElementById('mylovelytextbox');el.value = doc.getElementsByName('thisone')[0].value;" value="Click"><br /> <iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" src="2.html" id="mylovelyiframe"></iframe> </body> </html>
```

Thanks a lot, Stano!

Comment: It's not that complicated... what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried lot of things, i searched last 1 hour. If its not complicated, can you answer my question :(

Comment: @AtaGülalan When you want this "auto-fill" to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first fix those missing tags

```html
<iframe src="2.html" id="mylovelyiframe"></iframe>
</head><body>
```

and add some doctype, then you can use

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = document.getElementById('mylovelyiframe');
var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
var elem = document.getElementById('mylovelytextbox');
elem.value = doc.getElementsByName('thisone')[0].value;
</script>
```

Comment: Oh? It is not working i think.
My Code is like that:

<html>
<head>
<title>IFRAME TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" id="mylovelytextbox"><input type="button" onClick="var iframe = document.getElementById('mylovelyiframe');console.log(iframe,doc,el);var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;var el = document.getElementById('mylovelytextbox');el.value = doc.getElementsByName('thisone')[0].value;" value="Click"><br />
<iframe src="2.html" id="mylovelyiframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

I did anything wrong?

Comment: @AtaGülalan For me it works, check also your `2.html` file: `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><form method="get" action=""><input type="hidden" name="thisone" value="mylovelychangedvalue"></form></body></html>` Works good in Firefox, but Chrome restricts frames usage.

Comment: It is not working in chrome. How can i run this code on chrome?

Comment: Don't test iframes in Chrome with `file://` protocol. Chrome always reports in console: `Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.` (open it with `Ctrl+Shift+J`) Either use `http://localhost/1.html` or switch to Firefox.

Comment: You can use iframes in your pages, it works good also in Chrome but only with http:// protocol. For testing/developing iframes with Chrome either install [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#641) or something similar, or use some less strict browser (for example Firefox has many great features and tools for web developers ;-))

Comment: OH! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I UPLOADED MY SITE AND IT WORKS! THANKS A LOT!