# Fill form contents automatically on a external website with form data from mysql using curl and php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, curl

I am learning using php with mysql and curl .
I need pointers for filling up the form contents automatically on a external website with form data from mysql using curl and php. After a form is submitted successfully it displays a confirmation page.

The external form is at : https://get.uber.com/new-signup/

The form tag in the code is :

```
    <form id="signup-form" action="/signup_submit/" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
```

Please advise.....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

See [Javascript - Fill input with iframe-in Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450978/javascript-fill-input-with-iframe-in-value)

It is done with javascript on the page the iframe is displayed.

Example from linked post:

```
<iframe src="2.html" id="mylovelyiframe"></iframe>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var iframe = document.getElementById('mylovelyiframe');
   var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
   var elem = document.getElementById('mylovelytextbox');
   elem.value = doc.getElementsByName('thisone')[0].value;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the general idea is to take a look at the source of the page you wish to automate. find the url where the form submits to, and find all the names of the form fields. also pay attention to hidden fields that you may also need to provide. then you use to curl to simulate submitting the form. some of the curl options you need to provide are CURLOPT_URL and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. also, please be aware that the form you provided is protected with a captcha, and you will probably not be able to automate it without a lot of work. using developer tools in your browser of choice is your best tool for reverse engineering the way forms work with your browser.